# Define multiple namespaces with JDOM

Tags: xml, rdf, xml-namespaces, jdom

I have found that JDOM is a good choice to create xml files, and in my case I need to create one with multiple namespaces like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#">
  <v:VCard rdf:about="164">
    <v:fn />
  </v:VCard>
</rdf:RDF>
```

But I don't know how to define the second namespace into the root element. What I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <v:VCard xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#" rdf:about="164">
    <v:fn />
  </v:VCard>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here is my code:

```
Namespace rdf = Namespace.getNamespace("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
Namespace v = Namespace.getNamespace("v", "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#");
Element rootElement = new Element("RDF", rdf);
//rootElement.setAttribute("IdontWantoThis", "IdontWantoThis", v);
Element mainElement = new Element("VCard", v);
mainElement.setAttribute("about", "164", rdf);
Element element = new Element("fn", v);
mainElement.addContent(element);
rootElement.addContent(mainElement);
doc.addContent(rootElement);
```

If I use the commented line I get this other undesirable thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#" v:IdontWantoThis="IdontWantoThis">
  <v:VCard rdf:about="164">
    <v:fn />
  </v:VCard>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I know that there are some RDF specific libraries for java, but I just want to create a simple xml file, dont want to work with models, ontologies, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a namespace on an element even if the element does not need it immediately....

```
Element rootElement = new Element("RDF", rdf);
rootElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(v);
```

See [`addNamespaceDeclaration()`](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#addNamespaceDeclaration(org.jdom2.Namespace))

Comment: Brilliant! The very most simple and fast solution never given to me.